# Searching for Apple iPhone Provisioning Assistant

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I'm trying to get started with an iPhone project.  The book I am working with (Sam's 24 Hours) says to go to the Developer Portal, which will present the Development Provisioning Assistant, and then click on the Launch Assistant button.  My screen does not look like the picture in the book, and I can't find a Provisioning Assistant *anywhere!*.  Is my book out of date (Feb 2010)? Or am I blind? My book indicates that I should be able to do this with a free account, but perhaps I need a paid account?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following link describes the requirements to get provitioning profiles.

[iOS development guide: managing devices and digital identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW9)

Comment: sorry, I 3-year-old link I don't maintain myself, has changed. That's no reason for down voting the answer.